# Propensity Score Matching Between Pre and Post Group

Tags: propensity-scores

I am trying to understand if it is an acceptable practice when match treatment groups with control groups (either one to one or one to many) between a pre (control) group versus a post (experimental) group.

Comment: Do you have two treatment groups with one time point each? If so, in what sense is this pre-post and not just two groups (i.e., the usual application of matching)?